# Changes to Access database do not persist when running app in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-access, datagridview

I am creating a library application in Visual Studio 2010 Professional and Access 2010. I bind the Access database to Visual Studio. When I fill out the fields and click submit I can see the new record in the DataGridView, but when I close the application the new record is not saved and I have to input the record again.

Can somebody help me to know why when I input the new record through the application the record is not saved in the database?

Comment: How do you look at your database? Are you sure that the database is the same? (Warning DB in Project Folder and DB in Output dir A.K.A. BIN\DEBUG or BIN\X86\DEBUG)

Comment: I see it with the DataGridView. Yes Sr. it is the same. I see the new record in the DataGridView, I close the application and when I open the application again the new record is no longer in the DataGridView or database.

Comment: How do you have implemented the submit operation? Can you paste the code?

Comment: Do you have the database file listed in the project items? If yes what is its property Copy To the Output Directory?

Comment: Private Sub btnCreateAccount_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateAccount.Click
        LibraryMembersTableAdapter.Insert(txtMemberID.Text, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtCity.Text, txtState.Text, txtZip.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text)

   lblConfirm.Text = "Record Created"
   txtMemberID.Text = ""
   txtFirstName.Text = ""
   txtLastName.Text = ""
   txtAddress.Text = ""
   txtCity.Text = ""
   txtState.Text = ""
End Sub

Comment: In the Copy to Output says = Copy always

Comment: HELLO MY FRIENDS I THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP. NOW IT IS WORKING. YOU GUYS ARE SO SMART AND I LEARN SO MUCH FROM YOUR ANSWERS. THANK YOU, THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Answer (score 9):

It is a very common situation. You have your database file (the MDB or ACCDB file) listed between your project items. If you click on this file and look at the properties window you will see a property called `Copy to the output directory`. If this property is set to `Copy Always` then every time you start a debug session the database file listed in your project items is copied by VS in the output directory (usually BIN\DEBUG). Of course this copy doesn't contain the records inserted in your last debug session and you think that your previous insert has failed.

Setting this property to `Copy If Newer`, the mentioned behavior will happen only if you change the database schema manually.

Setting this property to `Copy Never`, will let you manually copy the database file.