# How do I avoid the loss of data after I rerun (debug) my program in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2013

I want to add a new record into an Access database which is already populated with data. When I initially run (debug in Visual Studio) and add the record, it is saved into that specific table. Then when I close the program and run it again, the record is nowhere to be seen. The previously populated data is still there however.

Comment: Is the database deployed as part of the project?

Comment: I found the solution. thanks for your input. :) It was just a simple setting in the properties window of my database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changes to Access database do not persist when running app in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420999/changes-to-access-database-do-not-persist-when-running-app-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys, i found a solution. I changed my database's properties "copy to output" from "copy always" to "copy if newer". Such a simple solution for all my struggles...

Answer (score 0):

Debugging stores everything in a temporary folder.

To avoid this, goto your project folder, goto bin/Debug and open it from there.

Comment: Thank for your input. Will keep it in mind if such a thing happens again. I found a solution, just changed a setting in my database's properties window. :)