# Can not save data into access through VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

When i run the code, input any data and save the data, then go check the access db file in the debug folder then the data des get saved. But if i rerun the code, all the data gets erased from the previous run.

I do want the data go get saved and stay there once i rerun the code.

Comment: Is the database part of the project?  Or is it somewhere else that you specify in the connection string?  And why the Access-vba tag? Is it VB.NET or not?

Comment: Check the property Copy To Output Directory associated with your database file listed between the project files. It should be set to Copy Never

Comment: Ok never mind, seems i havent looked properly, the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420999/changes-to-access-database-do-not-persist-when-running-app-in-visual-studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17147249/1070452 is also from @Steve and very helpful