# Update typed dataset doesn't affect database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I wrote code for updating MS-Access database. Buth the change is only visible in typed dataset and gridView. Code:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();DATA SOURCE = path_to_db");
            productAdapter = new ProductsTableAdapter();
            dataTable = new ProductsDataTable();
            productAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
        }
```

and update:

```
public void update()
        {
            this.Validate();
            var x = dataTable.GetChanges();
            int y = productAdapter.Update(dataTable);
            dataTable.AcceptChanges();
        }
```

But the table in database is not update at all. What else should I do to commit changes to database?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. How is the `update()` method getting called? (For my test I called it from a `button1_Click` event handler for a button on my form.)

Comment: A daabasecommand has four queries : Select, Update, Delete, and Insert.  The Update will not work unless you have the text for the insert.  The Adapter will create the command.  A CommandBuilder class will automatically take a Select query and generate the other three.

Comment: I have another form. Form is filled with info from the selected row. After changing info in second form I'm updating rows and call update() as callback after returning from the second form.
But as far as I know I have Update Command created automatically by the typed dataset. And 'y' variable shows that one row should be affected...

Comment: If you have included the database file in your Visual Studio project then make sure you are not falling victim to the (common) problem described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19420999/2144390).

Comment: Finally! Thank you very much! I was struggling with this for couple of days. How can I avoid this if there is none a word about  in .net documentation connected with database (or I can't find it)... If you post new reply I mark your answer as correct. Thank you once again!

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but it's better for the site if we mark this question as a duplicate.