# Can't insert data into access database using vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a little problem with my coding. there's no error when I'm running the program. But, I can't insert the data into my access database. Actually, I have the same problem with Update/editing data. I'm working with Visual basic 2010

```
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=dbBantuDong.accdb;"
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbCounter VALUES ('Corp',1,3)"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Success")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changes to Access database do not persist when running app in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19420999/2144390).

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Click on your database file on the **Solution Explorer** of your project. In the properties window, you can see `Copy To Output Directory` property.

There are three options available:

Select `Do not copy` if the file is **never** to be copied to the output directory.

Select `Copy always` if the file is **always** to be copied to the output directory.

Select `Copy if newer` if the file is to be copied **only when it is newer than an existing** file of the same name in the output directory.

Make the change accordingly. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your response.. i think the problem is when i made the connection between my project and the database.. my program update the database in the folder bin/debug, meanwhile the connection is made to database which is located outside the bin folder.. after i change the connection to the right folder the database is starting to be updated.. i'm using application.startUpPath (it returned the bin/debug location).. so i changed the connection to that folder.. what do you think?is it the right solution for my problem ?

Comment: no problem, don't forget to mark it as helpful if it helped you