# Changes not showing in Access Database

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

I'm very new to visual basic and I am trying to add, remove and edit entries to a MS Access Database. I have a data grid view in Visual Studio where I can see all my entries over multiple runs (saves at the end of the session). I have a 2 part problem:

1. Every time I enter a new entry into my visual studio, my database table does not get updated.
2. When I try to remove the selected row followed by save, the entire table gets deleted.

Please see snippet of my code below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CustomerProfileTableBindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub

Private Sub AddConfiguration_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CustomerProfileDataSet.CustomerProfileTable' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.CustomerProfileTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CustomerProfileDataSet.CustomerProfileTable)

End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    CustomerProfileTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
    CustomerProfileTableTableAdapter.Update(CustomerProfileDataSet.CustomerProfileTable)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    Dim iExit As DialogResult
    iExit = MessageBox.Show("Confirm if you want to remove current selection", "Remove Selection", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If iExit = DialogResult.Yes Then
        CustomerProfileTableBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    End If

End Sub
```

[I use add to add new rows to my table and then I use the save button to endEdit and Update my table and use a removeCurrent to remove current selection followed by save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYNGs.png)

I apologize if this question has been asked previously but I could not find the right solution anywhere and since I am very new to this, having a hard time trying to figure this out.

I am using VS 2017 and MS-Access 2016.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changes to Access database do not persist when running app in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420999/changes-to-access-database-do-not-persist-when-running-app-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Unfortunately, I did try this and this does not solve my issue.

Comment: Code should be posted as text in question, not images.

Comment: Apologize for that. I have edited my question accordingly.